# Model relationship types in cakePhP

Tags: cakephp

I have checked out the cookbook web site of cakephp that there are four types Model relationship:
http://book.cakephp.org/view/79/Relationship-Types

Since the one I am more familiar with is belongsTo, 

I am not sure when I need to use hasManay and HABTM. 

What will be the result to my web site if I used a wrong Model relationship type?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`belongsTo` and `hasMany` are a pair and express a one-to-many relationship. One model *belongs to* another (i.e. it has a `other_model_id` field), while the other way around that other model *has many* records in the model that *belongs to it*. It's two sides of the same coin.

`hasAndBelongsToMany` is Cake's term for a many-to-many relationship. [Here's a primer](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) on this type of relationship. You use this when both models can *have many* of the other model, e.g. People-People friend relationships. A many-to-many relationship between two models entails three tables: `model_a`, `model_b` and `model_a_model_b`. If you're trying to use this type of relationship without the third table, you'll probably just get a bunch of errors.

Comment: This diagram may help you visualize the different types of relationships: http://mboffin.com/stuff/ruby-on-rails-data-relationships.png